# Create "Dynamic" XML File?

Tags: php, xml, dynamic

I'm working on a project which involves a player which is reading several XML files I have to get information such as: Where the images are stored, what the links should be, what the audio file is etc.

This player is going to be used for many different scenarios so I feel like instead of customizing an XML file for each use, we should have one XML file which is generated based on the scenario.

How could I go about implementing this so that the XML file itself is able to get values from a database and then replace the necessary variables? I think that PHP may be a possible solution but the XML files are being called by a flash and non-flash player which I do not think are able to execute php files.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP would be executed by the web server when the XML file is fetched. You can use [DOM XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to generate the XML.

Happy to give more assistance if you need it, although reading the manual would be a good start :)

Comment: Ok I have read some of the manual and it is definitely what I need so thanks for that. If you could just help me further go in the right direction that would be great. I need something that will take an existing xml file and then update the values in it to match the scenario. What part should I be looking at to accomplish this and what type of file will I be making to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You have two options. 1) you could recreate the XML file using the DOM XML API or 2) you can output the existing XML as a string and use `str_replace` to replace variable parts (perhaps using a placeholder something like `{{audio_file}}`.

The question is where your variables are coming from. How do you plan on passing them to the script?

Comment: Ok I think option 2 is my best bet. I have been able to output the XML as a string within a php file. I want my main XML file to be able to access this string as if it is an XML file however. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to have a web server set up to execute your PHP scripts. You should be able to configure your server to use an `.xml` extension and serve the correct content type. Then you can reference the file by URL as you would any other XML file.

Comment: I am looking for the same content.  The link you provided (http://in3.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php) seems to be not found.  Shall you please give me current link.